# I have an react website running on AWS but now when I do any changes in it , it is showing in files but not on browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have an react website running on AWS but now when I do any changes in it , it is showing in files but not on browser

I tried in private window , different system but it is loading the data which was updated first time.

I tried in private window , different system but it is loading the data which was updated first time.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is showing in files but not on browser"?

Comment: means when m checking through ftp files have new code but when i am loading my website on browser it is showing old code

Comment: even if in any system where site is uploading for the first time it is showing old data only

Comment: Sorry but you're missing some important details here... please update your question with what's your deploy infrastructure (S3? EC2? Transfer Family? Beanstalk?  Something else?) and CI/CD pipeline if any... "checking trough FTP files" doesn't give any hint on what AWS services you are using.

Comment: I have installed on amazon linux 2023 EC2 instance and then react app. then i configured ftp. my react files placed at ec2-user/folder/ and website is running from this folder location

Comment: also using mongodb open ssl

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have installed amazon ec2 instance.. 
on it i have installed my react and node app.. i uploaded files using filezilla..it is showing everything fine on my browser. then i updated few files in my filezilla . but my website is showing old data. i tried on different systems, on private window but it is showing old data only.

Comment: It resolved using command npm run build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved using command npm run build
as production build was not getting update